# What Are The Differences Of Git Commands on BitBucket In Comparison Of GitHub?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have been using Github for awhile. I start to use BitBucket my private repositories. I find git commands are not the same on BitBucket than GitHub. For example, a Git command "git push origin master" works on GitHub, but not on BitBucket,

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The following is an output of the command "git remote -v":

```
master  https://myAccount@bitbucket.org/myAccount/codingexercise.git (fetch)
master  https://myAccount@bitbucket.org/myAccount/codingexercise.git (push)
```

Comment: It might just be different versions of git you're running locally

Comment: What? From the point of view of a local repository on your computer, there's no difference. To git, they are just "remotes". You could even set up two remotes for the same local project, one for github and one for bitbucket and the operations available to you to interact with them would be the same.

Comment: There should be no difference. Github and BitBucket are just remotes. Git is the same program on your computer no matter what. It sounds like your BitBucket repository is misconfigured or you typoed a command.

Comment: You need to post the actual commands and the actual output. Also, execute `git remote` and post the results.

Comment: That's `git remote -v` please.

Comment: For this question it is probably enough to know that there *is* a remote, but yes, add the `-v` to show us that you have proper url's configured.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs. Based on your inputs, I updated my question.

Comment: You have a remote named `master`, and no remote named `origin`. The command `git push origin master` reads as `git push REMOTENAME BRANCHNAME`, since you have named your remote `master` as well, you probably need to do `git push master master`, but it is probably not a good idea if you're confused about the meaning of all this to name different things the same

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I don't think that I named the remote name as "master" knowingly. I guess that I need to fix the problem first.